# Controller is not recognizing

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, ngroute

I have a controller defined in script.js called HelloController which was working before i added the ngRoute and made to route. The error that shows is

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=HelloController

I have checked the documentations about this error, but i couldn't get what is the problem actually with the code. the following is the code

**script.js**

```
// Code goes herE


   (function(){
        angular.module('myapp',[])
       .controller(['$scope','$http',

          function HelloController($scope,$http){
             $scope.helloTo = "angular";
          $scope.hide = true;

 $scope.search = (NameToSearch)=>{

    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+NameToSearch).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
    $scope.data=response.data;

    console.log($scope.data.repos_url);
    $http.get($scope.data.repos_url).then((resp)=>{
        //console.log(resp);
        $scope.repos=resp.data;
        if(resp.data){
            console.log("hide scope")
            $scope.hide=false;
        }
        console.log(resp);
        }).then(()=>{
            if($scope.repos){
                $scope.hide= false;
            }
        })
    });

    }
   }
   ]);
    })();
```

**configuaration.js**

```
    angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute'])
         .config(['$routeProvider',function configu($routeProvider) {
      // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/view1");
      console.log("HERE")
       $routeProvider.when('/',{
           templateUrl:'view1.html',
            controller:"HelloController"
        });
     }      
    ]);
```

**index file header is as follows**

```
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
      <script src = 

   "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
  </script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet"
     href = 
 "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular- 
 material.min.css">
     <script src = 
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular- 
  material.min.js"></script>
     <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular- 
ui-router.min.js"></script> -->
     <script  
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular- 
   route.min.js.map"></script>
     <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular- 
    route.js"> 
    </script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="configuration.js"></script>

   </head>
```

would be nice if someone could help because i'm new to angular

Comment: Created working copy of your code in pluker, check the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=HelloController` is because the order of load the files in your index.html is incorrect. I'll mention this in my full explanation...

Have so many things that i'll must do. Some things is required in order to work, and another is my personal recommendation. Follow:

- Required Things:

  - You must use `ng-app` inside your index.html to define where will render the content of your $scope. Your code doesn't had this tag;
  - To use 'ngRoute' you must add the element `ng-view` inside your index.html. Is in it that when will be render the 'templateUrl' which you define in your routes. According you change your uri, the ng-route will render the templates inside it. The usual is put this inside your body inside a div tag. i.g.: `<div ng-view></div>`;
  - When you will declare a controller you must make the call to `angular.module('app')`, but this call can't be equal in the main call that is done to our configuration.js (`angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);`). You doesn't use block quotes after 'app', because this represent that you are declaring again the app;
  - To use 'ngRoute' you must use `<base href="/"/>`. This tag will define how will be you initial URI value to your routes. Usual this value is defined to `href` match the first routes; https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase
  - Inside your index.html you are loading firstly the script.js, where is defined the controller and after your are loading the configuration.js, where is declared the ng-app. The main file in your AngularApp. To load this resource, you need pay attention in the order of the load. With time you will be able to recognize this in your first look, but for while save this order to load your resources inside index.html;

1° - Dependencies  (angular, angular-route, jQuery, etc);
2° - The file where is defined the `angular.module('myApp',[])`. In your case, the configuration.js;
3° - Controllers, Services, Configuration, Filters, Modules, etc;

- Inside your config there is a syntax error: `configu(function()...`;

Recommendation for your app AngularJS:

- Use comments inside your index.html to define where is the load area to each file. example:
  `<!-- Dependencies files -->`
  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>`
  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>`
  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>`
  ``
  `<!-- App, Routes-->`
  `<script src="configuration.js"></script>`
  `<script src="script.js"></script>`

`<!-- Controllers -->`
`<script src="example.controller.js"></script>`

`<!-- Services -->`
`<script src="example.services.js"></script>`

- I prefer declare my routes in other file, but this is possible in the same file that is declared the app.main;
- Don't declare controllers, services, routes, etc using nested codes. For example in your configuration.js:
- Use `var app = angular.module("myapp");` 
   `app.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']`;
   `app.controller('HelloController', function HelloController(...` 
  instead 
  `angular.module('myapp', ['$scope', '$http']).controller(...'`;
- Use service to make request. The angular have the services. The recommendation is use $http in this component https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service;

This is implementaion work as a charm :D :
index.html

**`**

```
<html  ng-app="myapp">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="configuration.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <base href="/" />
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

configuration.js

```
    angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider

                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/view1.html',
                    controller: 'HelloController'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        });
```

script.js

```
    (function () {
        var app = angular.module('myapp');

        app.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

        app.controller('HelloController', function HelloController($scope, $http) {
            $scope.helloTo = "angular";
            $scope.hide = true;

            $scope.search = (NameToSearch) => {

                $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + NameToSearch).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.data = response.data;

                    console.log($scope.data.repos_url);
                    $http.get($scope.data.repos_url).then((resp) => {
                        //console.log(resp);
                        $scope.repos = resp.data;
                        if (resp.data) {
                            console.log("hide scope")
                            $scope.hide = false;
                        }
                        console.log(resp);
                    }).then(() => {
                        if ($scope.repos) {
                            $scope.hide = false;
                        }
                    })
                });
            };

        });
    })();
```

Comment: i have tried by giving it with the html tag and as well as in the body tag but both case does have this error

Comment: @HarikrishnanS ok, but declare ng-app is mandatory to your angular application.

Comment: yes this is a good explanation and it seems working though i have solved this issue it was only because the controller name wasn't mentioned. and thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your script.js, define the angular module `app` one time and then in any script file just register the controller on that module `app.contoller`.

Here is a working Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uWXnAkbAbJIb7jJEXZTP?p=preview